# Can TextIO write to prefixes derived from the window maxTimestamp?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am processing a windowed stream of PubSub messages and I would like to archive them to GCS.  I'd like the archived files to have a prefix that's derived from the window timestamp (something like gs://bucket/messages/2015/01/messages-2015-01-01.json).  Is this possible with TextIO.Write, or do I need to implement my own FileBasedSink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the recently added feature for windowed writes in `TextIO`. Please see the [documentation for TextIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html), in particular see `withWindowedWrites` and `to(FilenamePolicy)`. This feature is also present in `AvroIO`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply looking for the function [`TextIO.Write.Bound<String>.withSuffix()`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/TextIO.Write#withSuffix-java.lang.String-) or [`TextIO.Write.Bound<String>.to()`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/TextIO.Write#to-java.lang.String-)? It seems these would allow you to provide a suffix or prefix for the output filename.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, TextIO.Write does not support operation in streaming mode – writing to GCS is tricky, e.g., because you can't write to a file concurrently from multiple workers and you can't append to files once they close. We have plans to add streaming support to TextIO.

You'll get the best support for this today using BigQuery rather than GCS – because we already support BigQuery writes during streaming, and you choose which table you write to based on the window name, and BigQuery supports writes from many different workers at once.

Comment: Dan, why cant this be done with TextIO.Write.Bound.withSuffix ? why is it different for streaming? after all, streaming can be seen as a recurring job and each job can write at the end of each job

Comment: The string passed to .withSuffix() is a compile-time constant. Also, TextIO.Write cannot currently be used with the streaming runner.

Comment: sorry my ignorance. whats the point of having the suffix hardcover at compile time then? (given i can also concatenate that at compile time without withSuffix?) seems if each window could have a different file name, wouldnt be an issue concurrent job writes

Comment: The `withSuffix` command is used to specify a pattern for files. `TextIO` produces many files of the form prefix-00000-of-00010suffix. So you might to `withSuffix(".json")` so that the files all have the `.json` extension. See: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/TextIO.Write#to-java.lang.String- or https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/avro-io#writing for an example.

Answer (score -2):

TextIO.Write ought to work. No need for custom filesink.

In your case, you want to write your PubSub messages to an output text file - not locally, but on remote GS. You ought to be able to use:
 PCollection .apply.TextIO.Write().to(

Since you are processing a stream of PubSub messages, your window is unbounded and your PubSub data source already provides a timestamp for each element in the PCollection.

If you wish to assign a timestamp, your ParDo transform needs to use a DoFn that outputs elements using ProcessContext.outputWithTimestamp().

In summary, you can use TextIO.Write aftre ensuring the elements in your PCollection are output with timestamp.

Comment: this doesn't seem to answer the question. he already knows how to write to GCS. hes asking about modifying the output filename.