# Write each row received over PubSub to its own file on Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I am receiving messages via pubsub. Each message should be stored in its own file in GCS as rough data, execute some processing on the data, and then save it to big query- having the file name in the data.

Data should be seen immediately  in BQ after received.

**Example:**

```
data published to pubsub : {a:1, b:2} 
data saved to GCS file UUID: A1F432 
data processing :  {a:1, b:2} -> 
                   {a:11, b: 22} -> 
                   {fileName: A1F432, data: {a:11, b: 22}} 
data in BQ : {fileName: A1F432, data: {a:11, b: 22}}
```

the idea is that the processed data is stored in BQ having a link to the Rough data stored in GCS.

Here is my code.

```
public class BotPipline {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
    options.setRunner(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.class);
    options.setProject(MY_PROJECT);
    options.setStagingLocation(MY_STAGING_LOCATION);
    options.setStreaming(true);

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    PCollection<String> input = pipeline.apply(PubsubIO.Read.subscription(MY_SUBSCRIBTION));

    String uuid = ...;
    input.apply(TextIO.Write.to(MY_STORAGE_LOCATION + uuid));

    input
    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String,String>(){..}).named("updateJsonAndInsertUUID"))
    .apply(convertToTableRow(...)).named("convertJsonStringToTableRow"))
            .apply(BigQueryIO.Write.to(MY_BQ_TABLE).withSchema(tableSchema)
    );
    pipeline.run();
}
```

My code doesn't run since  writing unbounded collections in  TextIO.Write  is not supported.
After some research I found I have a few options to workaround this issue:

1. creating a custom Sink in data flow
2. implement writing to GCS as my own DoFn
3. access the window of the data using the optional BoundedWindow

I have no idea how to start.
Can anyone provide me code for one of the following solutions, or give me a different solution which matches my case. (providing the code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is #2 - a simple `DoFn` that creates the files according to your data. Something like this:

```
class CreateFileFn extends DoFn<String, Void> {
  @ProcessElement
  public void process(ProcessContext c) throws IOException {
    String filename = ...generate filename from element...;
    try (WritableByteChannel channel = FileSystems.create(
            FileSystems.matchNewResource(filename, false),
            "application/text-plain")) {
      OutputStream out = Channels.newOutputStream(channel);
      ...write the element to out...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where do I add where to write?
`out.write(c, "gs://my-bucket/outputs/" + fileName"); `   ??   It doesn't give me this option. 
can you please edit your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Are you asking about how to implement ...generate filename from element... ?

Comment: no, my question is how to upload streaming data to storage, each publish from pubsub to its own file

Comment: Hmm. To upload each element in a PCollection to its own file, you need apply ParDo.of(new CreateFileFn()) to the collection, as described in my answer. Can you clarify what is the difficulty you're having with that?

Comment: my question is if it should be done in the regular http request to storage or it should be in a different way costumed to dataflw. if so please provide me the unique code. didn't find any examples.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how much more clear my answer can get - I gave you the code for the DoFn and gave you the code for applying it. You need to do `input.apply(ParDo.of(new CreateFileFn()))` in your main program, and fill in the blank parts of `CreateFileFn` which are entirely specific to your application so I can't write them for you.

Comment: I have very similar requirements. The reason is , writing to gcs like this gives me idempotency in terms of files written , so even if i process duplicate events i overwrite the same files with same data. But this raises 2 questions ,1) if i were to use standard textIO or avroIO , then i need to do windowing. Can we guarantee idempotency in that scenario ? Are windows partially processed in case of pipeline failures or is it binary success failure scenario i.e either the whole window is written to multiple gcs sharded files or nothing is written ?